# jquery detach with find

Tags: jquery, html

Why does this not work

```
$rows = $("tbody").detach().find("tr");
```

but this does?

```
$rows = $("tbody").find("tr").detach();
```

I think the second way gets the set of "tr"'s and uses some sort of .each to detach them. I would think it would be more efficient, if there is a way to make it work, to detach the whole body once, and then get the tr's from it...?

Comment: Those snippets attempt to do different things. What do you want to do, detach the tbody, or the tr elements? The first snippet is searching the already detached tbody element, _not_ detaching the table rows. The second snippet is correct in your case I think.

Comment: Well because I am detaching all tr elements in tbody, they are trivially different in my case, I can always wrap a <tbody> if necessary. Anyways, My point it that I think $rows should contain the same value in both cases. Why does it not?

Comment: I get the same result in both cases when I test it. What does your markup look like? How do the two versions of `$rows` differ? Are you running both versions of code on clean documents (as opposed to running on, and then running the other on the result)?

Comment: hum, OK that's odd, I was using $rows.each. All I did was switch between the two statements above and I got different results.

Comment: Is there an issue with using `.each()` on a set of detached nodes?

Comment: @Rob - actually you were right. That was the issue. I thought I took care of that but apparently I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

`$rows` in fact does have the same value, however in the first example the `tbody` tag is missing from the DOM so you need to add it back in.

Note also that

`$rows = $("tbody").detach().find("tr");` (around **100ms** to detach and store 500 `tr` elements in an array)

is significantly more efficient than:

`$rows = $("tbody").find("tr").detach();` (around **170ms** to detach and store 500 `tr` elements in an array)

Answer (score 0):

First one detatching on $("tbody") and second statement detatching on rows of the table.

Comment: Yes, I know, but my question is why is the value of $rows different in each case?